# Do ASP.NET worker threads spend most of their active time in a blocked state?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to determine the role of ASP.NET worker threads. My IIS 7 installation defaulted to allowing a maximum of 25 worker threads, whereas I would have otherwise set it to 1.

When a user requests an `.aspx` page, I understand that that request will retrieve a worker thread. But does the loading of each of the images on that page also grab a worker thread? And once an image is retrieved, is the worker thread that retrieved it also responsible for transmitting it to the user (via blocking-tcp-sockets?)?

Comment: Why in the world would you want IIS to use 1 worker thread?

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Well Chris, that parameter is made configurable, so that people can *configure* it to suite their needs. It is highly uncommon to set it to one, but I'm sure there are scenarios where you want to do this. For example if you don't want IIS chew into much of you processing power while still occasionally allowing it processing a request or two. I'm sure there are also other conceivable scenarios.

Comment: @zespri I disagree. I don't believe there is any conceivable scenario that you would want to limit IIS to 1 worker thread. If you want to limit it's resources it has many better constructs for that. You can control memory usage and CPU utilization limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's walk through how a web request to an ASPX page looks to a user and their browser.

The user navigates their browser to the ASPX page.  On the server, IIS recognizes this as an ASP.NET request and routes it to the .NET handlers for processing, which includes taking a worker thread, processing the page, and delivering the resulting HTML back to the user's browser.  This does not include delivering the actual images, JavaScript files, CSS files, and other external resources - just the resulting HTML from the page itself goes back to the user's browser.

When the user's browser renders the page, it will then make additional requests for the other resources on the page - images, JavaScript files, etc.  When IIS receives the requests for these files, it will process them as static content, and therefore the ASP.NET handlers (and their worker processes) is not involved in processing or delivering the content.

Note that you *can* configure IIS to use the .NET handlers to process these types of requests, but for static content, IIS won't do that out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7's installer includes "Common Http Features->Static Content" when installing. This module is responsible for handling the static content and I do not believe it uses any worker threads.

One worker thread seems a bit meager though, even for a test server. If your code goes into a long process (say a long query) you will be blocked from running other pages waiting out a single worker process. What prompted you to wish to set it to 1?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which IIS version you are talking about, so [here is something](http://forums.iis.net/t/1139229.aspx/1) I read some time back on v5.1.

> When using ASPCompat and session state, the runtime may serialize requests to the same session to a single thread.
>
> Otherwise, by default, if you make 12 requests to your application to the sleeping page, ASP.NET will make each subsequent request wait until a thread is freed up by a previous request.  You can control this behavior via the  and  configuration settings(machine.config), where the number of concurrent threads is the difference between maxWorkerThreads and minFreeThreads.  Please also double-check that these settings arent set such that your application is only capable of processing one ASP.NET request concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you have blocking calls in your asp.net app code.

No if you respond to request with data that is all in memory.

Static Images should not be served via Asp.Net, a static file server like IIS or nginx should do this much faster.